# error on populating an empty array - react, mongodb, graphql

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, graphql, mern

I'm writing an app to use notes and have them stay persistent on a user's page. The code works if the user already has a note in their array, but a new user has an empty array, and it gives an error saying "text" is undefined.

```
const NoteForm = () => {
  const user = Auth.getProfile()
  console.log(user)
  const { data } = useQuery(QUERY_USER, {
    variables: { username: user.username },
  });
  
  const [noteText, setNoteText] = useState({
    text: data?.user.notes?.[0].text,
  });

  const [addNote, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_NOTE, {
    update(cache, { data: { addNote } })
  });
```

I tried writing an if/else statement around it a few different ways, but I have a useMutation below it that gives me the error that it cannot be used as a conditional statement, so I'm not sure where else I could put the if/else. My thought was to try some way of writing **if (!data.user.notes)** it populates an empty string on the page or a message asking for the user to input a note, but I don't know where or how to place that just yet.